# Elliptic integral and Arithmetic Geometric Mean

Tags: elliptic-integrals

For real numbers $0 < a < b$ we let
\begin{align*}
F(a,b) = 2\int_a^b \frac{dt}{\sqrt{(t^2-a^2)(b^2-t^2)}}
\end{align*}

Using some substitutions, we can show that
\begin{align*}
F(a,b) = \int_{a^2}^{b^2} \frac{dt}{\sqrt{t(t-a^2)(b^2-t)}} = \int_{-\infty}^0 \frac{dt}{\sqrt{t(t-a^2)(b^2-t)}}.
\end{align*}
(For the first one take $u = t^2$, we get the second from the first by substituting $u = \frac{t-b^2}{t-a^2}$)

I would like to show that
\begin{align*}
    F(a,b) = \int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{d\theta}{\sqrt{a^2\cos^2(\theta) + b^2\sin^2(\theta)}},
\end{align*}
but was unable to do so. From
\begin{align*}
    F(a,b) = \int_{-\infty}^0 \frac{dt}{\sqrt{t(t-a^2)(b^2-t)}},
\end{align*}
I substituted $\theta = -\arctan(t)$. Then $d\theta = -(t^2 + 1)^{-1}dt$ and the bounds become $\pi/2$ and $0$.
\begin{align*}
    F(a,b) &= \int_{\pi/2}^0 \frac{-(t^2 + 1)d\theta}{\sqrt{\tan(-\theta)(\tan(-\theta)-a^2)(b^2-\tan(-\theta))}}\\
    &= \int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{\sec^2(-\theta)d\theta}{\sqrt{\tan(-\theta)(\tan(-\theta)-a^2)(b^2-\tan(-\theta))}}\\
    &= \int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{d\theta}{\sqrt{\cos^4(-\theta)\tan(-\theta)(\tan(-\theta)-a^2)(b^2-\tan(-\theta))}}
\end{align*}
I am stuck here as I could not figure out how to show that this becomes
\begin{align*}
    \int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{d\theta}{\sqrt{a^2\cos^2(\theta) + b^2\sin^2(\theta)}}.
\end{align*}

I am fairly certain it should be possible given [this](https://ctnt-summer.math.uconn.edu/wp-content/uploads/sites/1632/2016/02/coxctnt.pdf) and [this](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-1-4757-3240-5_55).

Comment: Have a look at Jack d'Aurizio book https://cel.archives-ouvertes.fr/cel-01813978 chapter 11

Comment: Gauss proved this using the transformation $$ \sin\theta = \frac{2a \sin\phi}{a + b + (a - b)\sin^{2}\phi}$$ in the integral $$F(a, b) =\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{d\theta} {\sqrt{a^2\cos^2\theta+b^2\sin^2\theta} } $$ More details are available in [this post](https://paramanands.blogspot.com/2009/08/arithmetic-geometric-mean-of-gauss.html?m=0).